# Does 30% hydrogen peroxide eat away at platinum?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

if I soaked a platinum dish with 30% hydrogen peroxide, will it eventually eat away at it?

Comment: Nope. On the contrary, hydrogen peroxide will decompose pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @Ivan said, hydrogen peroxide will not corrode platinum, instead hydrogen peroxide will get decomposed.

[Catalytic decomposition of hydrogen peroxide by metals and alloys of the platinum group:](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021951769903261)

> The **catalytic decomposition of dilute aqueous solutions of hydrogen
>   peroxide** has been studied on a number of Group VIII metals and binary
>   alloys, including palladium-gold. The kinetics were measured at 27 °
>   as a function of catalyst composition and pH of the solution. In
>   neutral solution, the activity of the individual metals of Group VIII
>   was generally greater than those of Group VIII2, the order of specific
>   activity (per unit surface area) decreasing in the sequence $\ce{Pt > Os >
>  Ir > Pd > Ru > Rh}$. (...)

Other references:

1. http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0926337306001561/1-s2.0-S0926337306001561-main.pdf?_tid=a114888e-1c29-11e7-9622-00000aacb360&acdnat=1491635258_a3e20984dda9eaaf07e78f4814383b96
2. http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed080p788
3. http://jcsp.org.pk/ArticleUpload/2541-11513-1-CE.pdf